# Finding a parameter for two solutions in a field

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics

For what values of parameter $m$ does the equation have two solutions in field $Z_{13}$?
$$mx^2+2mx+(m+1)=0$$

So my guess for such problem would be to calculate the delta so that we get $\Delta = 4m$ and then all I can think of is using the formula for finding solutions so that we get $\frac{-b+-\sqrt{4m}}{2a}$. Then, we just check for each $m$ if there exists $\sqrt{4m}$ in this field.

This, though makinf the job done, seems like a brute force approach. Is there a better/faster one?

Comment: Have you learned about [quadratic residues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue)?

Comment: @JohnHabert - no, regretfully I haven't... But now after looking at it for a while - how does this help here?

Comment: Since $\sqrt{4m} = 2\sqrt{m}$, you will have solutions exactly when there is $n$ such that $n^2\equiv m \pmod{13}$.

Comment: @JohnHabert - thank you, that's a great fast way. However, this won't necessarily work for other problems like this, right? I mean - say we have $3x^2 +5x +m=0$, also in $Z_{13}$. Then, we have $\Delta = 12-12m \equiv m-1$ and we can't use such shortcut. That's why I'm curious about a general faster way than brute forcing to find a square root, not just for this specific example.

Comment: The same method would basically work. If you know all of the $m$ such that $\sqrt{m}$ can be found, then you can easily modify so that $\sqrt{m-1}$ can be found.

Comment: @JohnHabert - Mhm, I see. Thank you a lot again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate a little on the comments (and so this question can have an answer), there are more advanced techniques that you can use (like [quadratic reciprocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity) and the [Legendre symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol) though these tend to work better for testing if a specific number is a quadratic residue rather than finding them all). For small primes $p$, brute force is usually the fastest, especially when you switch from the residues classes of $\{0,1,2,...,p-1\}$ to the residue classes of $\{-\frac{p-1}{2},...,-2,-1,0,1,2,...,\frac{p-1}{2}\}$. This latter class makes it clear that you only need to check from $1^2 \pmod{p}$ up to $\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)^2 \pmod{p}$ to find all the quadratic residues $\bmod\ p$.